# SqL Design for Countries - States - Cities

Tags: sql

Hi I am developing a Simple Form with HTML drop downs for Countires, States , Cities. Adding Countries , States , Cities and updating them is done , no issues with that. Every thing working perfect . And the Problem comes here at the time of deleting(Let's say deactivating).

I have designed the Tables which are ideal for this type of Country ,state, city drop down by referring some sites in net. Like:

```
Countries Table:

   |SerialNo|CountryName|CountryId|Active|

States Table
   |SerialNo|StateName|StateId|CountryId|Active|


CitiesTable:
   |SerialNo|CityName|CityId|StateId|IsActive|
```

So at the time of deactivating any Country i am making Active="false", so deactivated Countries are not going to display in my grid. If do like this The States which are in that respective Countries should also become deactivate right.

So i did like this:
 SQL Query:

```
Update CountriesTable set Active='false' where CountryId= @CountryId
Update StatesTable set Active='false' where CountryId= @CountryId
```

As i have CountryId in both tables i could deactivate Countries,States in two tables.But how could i deactivate the Cities of Deactivated States?? There is a concept called Triggers in Sql Which updates other table after Data manipulating in a particular table , can i achieve my requirement with Triggers, or is there any good way to achieve it?

How could i achive it?

**I dont want to add one more column of CountryId to the citiestable**
Sorry for my bad english. Hope i am clear to all of you!! Any references , any Sql queries , any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: Note that not all countries have states (or, at least, the territorial divisions between countries and cities is not always called a state). You should indicate which DBMS you're using (though I'm moderately sure it is MS SQL Server; which version might matter, especially if it is archaic).  And yes, if you want the update of the status of a country to propagate to the states and cities, you'll use a trigger.  However, your trigger will need to adapt to setting `IsActive = 'true'` too; you won't want the trigger to set things to false still if you do that.

Comment: Also, you're going to want to include any ISO information for entities, if it exists - ie, [the country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).  There may be equivalent information for states (country subdivisions) and cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic `UPDATE` statement to set the `IsActive` column of the correct rows in the `Cities` table for a given country ID.

```
UPDATE Cities
   SET IsActive = 'false'
 WHERE StateID IN (SELECT StateID FROM States WHERE CountryID = @CountryID);
```

It will work in pretty much any SQL DBMS.  There may be other notations using join notations that would allow you to write it differently.

You'll have to incorporate that into a trigger for your DBMS using the relevant syntax for your DBMS.  Since you didn't identify which DBMS, we can't be sure (though, as I noted, there's a fair chance that it MS SQL Server).

Or you can redesign the schema and queries so that setting the country's `IsActive` state to false is sufficient to ensure that states or cities from the country are not shown — as advocated by [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589827/15168).

Note that your trigger should account for countries becoming active again; using `'false'` will not always be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is not required. When selecting `States`, join to `Countries` and filter on Country `IsActive`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Countries 
WHERE IsActive <> False;

SELECT s.*
FROM States s
INNER JOIN Countries c on c.CountryId = s.CountryId
WHERE c.IsActive <> False;
```